# Sychronise Combo Boxes with text values

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm having an issue with synchronizing two combo boxes where they contain text values.

There are two combo boxes, one for a brand name and the other is where the models for that particular brand should be populated.

When the user selects the Brand this window pops up.

[image]

This is the code behind the brand drop down

```
Me.cboProduct.RowSource = "SELECT ProductName FROM Boiler_Att_Qry WHERE Brand = Me.cboBrand.Value ORDER BY ProductName;"
```

Me.cboProduct = Me.cboProduct.ItemData(0)

I have tried the following code i saw on Microsoft but it still didn't work.

[Microsoft's help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb404901%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

```
hr(34) Me.cboCategories & Chr(34) & _
```

I'm guessing I have missed something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Me.cboProduct.RowSource = "SELECT ProductName FROM Boiler_Att_Qry WHERE Brand = cboBrand.Text ORDER BY ProductName;"
  Me.cboProduct = Me.cboProduct.ItemData(0)
```

I found that using `cbBrand.Text` to look refine the product list worked. The list now refines based on the brand.

I found this after many hours of testing various methods as well as the methods provided by you guys on here. I voted up each answer as they aided me to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Rowsource` property, try `Forms!<name of form>!cboBrand` instead of 'Me.cboBrand.Value'

Comment: Tried it but the cboBrand doesn't populate. 

WHERE Brand = Forms!Frm_Main!cboBrand.value ORDER BY ProductName;"
  Me.cboProduct = Me.cboProduct.ItemData(0)

Comment: What is the `RowSource` of `cboBrand`?

Comment: The row source is from a table. `SELECT [Brand_Tbl].[ID], [Brand_Tbl].[Brand Name] FROM Brand_Tbl;`

Comment: I think i figured out the issue will post in due course when the theory has been tested.

Answer (score 1):

Try building the query using VBA like so:

```
Me.cboProduct.RowSource = _
"SELECT ProductName FROM Boiler_Att_Qry WHERE Brand = '" _
& [Me]![cboBrand] _
& "' ORDER BY ProductName;"
```